# upper bound on third moment

Tags: probability, inequality, expectation

If I know that $EX^4=1$ and $EX\leq0$, how do I get an upper bound for $EX^3$? I know that by Jensen's inequality, $EX^3\leq1$, but I need the upper bound less than 1.

Comment: Do not post self-duplicates.